# Authorize.net payment failes but order created anyway

Tags: magento-2.0.7, authorize.net

When authorize.net payment fails - order still being generated(with status cancelled but anyway). How to prevent this?

They do it with two different calls. First - create order, then - request to authorize. Why?

In Magento1 this was in one function with try-catch. And on error - transaction with order just rolled back

Comment: you need to modify magento functionality by ovrriding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the issues with authorize.net payment method. If you want to use direct post authorize.net payment method then you need to check on live site with https domain. and you will check with live credentials. you will get success page after place order.

Thanks